# How to push jmeter results to influx multiple databases using back end listeners?

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, jmeter-plugins, listeners

I want to push JMeter results data to the influx. I am able to push results to a database that is fine. But now I want to push result data of first sampler result to one database and second sampler result to another database.

To do this I tried using multiple backend listeners for each sampler. But the all sampler results data will be pushed to the same database which is configured in the first backend listeners.

Can we use multiple backend listeners for multiple configuration. or if we can't then why?
I am usinginfluxdbBackend.listenerClient

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)

> By default JMeter sends metrics for all samplers accumulated under the samplerName `"all"`. If the Backend Listener `samplersList` is configured, then JMeter also sends the metrics for the matching sample names unless `summaryOnly=true`

So if you add 2 [Backend Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results) instances and configure them like:

- `summaryOnly`: `false`
- `samplersList`: `Sampler1` for first, `Sampler2` for second
- different `graphineHost` and/or `graphitePort` values

  [image: JMeter Backend Listener]

Comment: How do I configure for the following configuration (question edited to add a screenshot)

Comment: In the `org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb.InfluxdbBackendListenerClient` implementation you have `samplersRegexp` setting where you can define which samplers information to collect with this Listener. Also make sure to have `summaryOnly` set to `false`. See [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results - Part 2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2) article for detailed configuration if needed